# SCSS Style parent only while child is present

Tags: sass

I have the following scss snippet. When `.child` is present I want the `.container` to have a color of `yellow` I have code elsewhere which removes adds/removes the element with `.child` on it

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  color: red;
  :global {
    .child {
      background-color: black;
    }
    .container .child { <=== This obviously doesn't work but 
                             I need .container to be yellow only when child is present 
       color: yellow;
    }

  }
}
```

How do I represent that in scss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2):

Even though you're using SCSS, we still can't get around the fact that [There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/825011). In your code that add/removes the element with the `child` class, add an additional class to the parent `container` so that you can color it.